# java.lang.IllegalStateException ConstraintLayout does not have a NavController set for a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation, android-fragment-manager

I have an activity (`main`) with three fragments (first, second and third).  I included the 3 fragments in my activity (`activity_main.xml`) by using  `<include layout="@layout/content_main"/>`.
The `content_main.xml` is using `FragmentContainerView` with `id = nav_host_fragment`. And this is my `nav_graph.xml`:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/FirstFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/FirstFragment"
        android:name="com.example.makegroups.FirstFragment"
        android:label="@string/first_fragment_label"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_first">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment"
            app:destination="@id/SecondFragment" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/SecondFragment"
        android:name="com.example.makegroups.SecondFragment"
        android:label="@string/second_fragment_label"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_second">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_SecondFragment_to_FirstFragment"
            app:destination="@id/FirstFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_SecondFragment_to_ThirdFragment"
            app:destination="@id/ThirdFragment" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/ThirdFragment"
        android:name="com.example.makegroups.ThirdFragment"
        android:label="@string/third_fragment_label"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_third">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_ThirdFragment_to_FirstFragment"
            app:destination="@id/FirstFragment" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

I have a `floatingactionbutton`in my activity (`first fragment`starts first) and when I click on it, I open the `third fragment`.
On the `third fragment` I have a button (next) to navigate to the `first fragment`, and when I click on it, I am back to `first fragment` using:

```
Fragment frg = new FirstFragment();
FragmentManager fm = requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Now (while I am in the `first fragment`), I click on the button `next`(another button to navigate to the `second fragment`), then the app crashes. I found this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: View androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout{c9572fa V.E...... ........ 0,0-1440,2112} does not have a NavController set
```

Why I am getting this error? -I tried these suggestions [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate), without success.

I am using Java.

**EDIT:**
Read the last comment with **@Zain** to know why I got the error.

Comment: check this may be it will help you https://github.com/sunil-singh-chaudhary/Fragment-Nested-Child-Backpress

Comment: If you are in the first fragment and need to go to second fragment just this should work: 
 findNavController().navigate(R.id. action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bu using Navigation Architecture components, The NavController is the responsible for fragment transaction and managing the back stack instead of the Support `FragmentManager`.

So, instead of making tranditional framgnet transactions with `FragmentManager`

You can move from ThridFragment to the first one by:

```
 Navigation.findNavController(requireView()).navigate(R.id.action_ThirdFragment_to_FirstFragment);
```

Where `action_ThirdFragment_to_FirstFragment` is the id of the action you defined in the navigation graph to move from `ThridFragment` to `FirstFragment`

**UPDATE:**

As discussed from comments, besides replacing `FragmentManager` by `NavController` in all actions; there is another issue:

Missing of `action_FirstFragment_to_ThirdFragment` action  from the navigation graph.

Comment: I tried it, but I am getting the same error. Remember that I am in `the first fragment` and want to go to the `second fragment`. I tried this too: `NavHostFragment.findNavController(FirstFragment.this).navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment);`

Comment: I see, let me check it

Comment: I tried what you suggested on moving from  `3th` to `1st`, but it doesn't work. Therefore I tried with `FragmentManager`. But know I want to use/learn the `NavController`. I simply could not.

Comment: @carl now when you launch the app, `FirstFrag > SecondFrag` (no issues in this), but `FirstFrag > ThirdFrag > FirstFrag > SecondFrag` (the issue is here) right ?

Comment: app starts. can move from `1` to `2`, `2` to `1 back to `2` and from `2` to `3` and `3` to `1`. All of these without issues. When I click on the `floatingactionbutton` to move `1` > `3`, it's ok (using `FragmentManager`). But issues starts from here, cannot `3` > `1` (had to use `FragmentManager`)

Comment: Not sure if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60962539/constraintlayout-does-not-have-a-navcontroller-set-for-item-clicked-on-recyclerv) can give some clues.. I can't see other mistakes in your provided code

Comment: It's not related to my problem. I replaced every `NavHostFragment.findNavController(fragment)
                        .navigate(R.id.action_...);` to a `fragmentManager` and everything is ok. I don't know why this issue with `NavController`!!!!

Comment: I accepted your answer because you was on the right track. My problem was: I FORGOT TO PUT ONE ACTION. See my `nav_graph.xml`. I forgot `action_FirstFragment_to_ThirdFragment`. Therefore I had to use `FragmentManager` and the issues started. Now I can navigate through all the fragments using `NavController`.

Comment: Thanks @carl.. I will update it in the answer so it may help some body else around the globe.. Happy coding 

Answer (score 1):

```
navController = Navigation.findNavController(activity, R.id.nav_host_fragment)
```

Comment: I am in a `fragment` the `first fragment`. I cannot used what you suggest. I tried this: `NavHostFragment.findNavController(FirstFragment.this).navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment);`, but I am getting the same rror.

Answer (score 0):

when using the Navigation Component you should not handle the transactions yourself, instead you define the actions between each fragment and then access those directly like this

```
override fun onCreate(){
  val navController = this.findNavController()
  button.setOnClickListener{
     navController.navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment, null)
  }
}
```

and your `nav_graph` should be like this

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
app:startDestination="@id/FirstFragment">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/FirstFragment"
    android:name="com.example.makegroups.FirstFragment"
    android:label="@string/first_fragment_label"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_first">

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment"
        app:destination="@id/SecondFragment" />
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/SecondFragment"
    android:name="com.example.makegroups.SecondFragment"
    android:label="@string/second_fragment_label"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_second">

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_SecondFragment_to_FirstFragment"
        app:destination="@id/FirstFragment" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_SecondFragment_to_ThirdFragment"
        app:destination="@id/ThirdFragment" />
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/ThirdFragment"
    android:name="com.example.makegroups.ThirdFragment"
    android:label="@string/third_fragment_label"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_third">

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_ThirdFragment_to_FirstFragment"
        app:destination="@id/FirstFragment" />
</fragment>
```

Comment: You are using `Kotlin`. I don't want to handle the transactions by myself. I had to do it (it's not working for me!). And what is `findNavController()`?. The `nav_graph` you showed it's the same as mine.

Comment: I can use `NavHostFragment.findNavController(FirstFragment.this)
                        .navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment);`, but it dosen't work for me.

Comment: my bad, u should add this.findNavController(), will edit it in the answer, and yes nav graph is the same as yours cuz it is correct

Comment: your  `findNavContoller()` implemented like this:`public static NavController findNavController(@NonNull Fragment fragment) {

        View view = fragment.getView();
        if (view != null) {
            return Navigation.findNavController(view);
        }
        return null;
    }`

Comment: could you write that in your question? don't write code in comments

Answer (score 0):

```
val navController = Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.fragment_container)
navigate.navigate(R.id.fragment)
```